# Python find change value of a dictionary according to a specific key, recursively

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to implement a function in Python that takes a dictionary, a function and a list of keys. I want to apply the function to a value of the dictionary only if its associated key is in keys. The search for the key should be recursive.

I implemented a function but I obtain an infinite loop. I do not understand why. Here the snippet of my function:

```
def apply_recursively_on_dict(self, dic: dict, function: Callable, keys: List[str]):
    for key, val in dic.items():
        while isinstance(val, dict):
            self.apply_recursively_on_dict(val, function, keys)
        assert not isinstance(val, dict)
        if key in keys or keys == "":
            dic[key] = function(val)
```

I obtain an infinite loop.

Here an example of a dictionary I am using:

```
dict = 
{'A_AB': {'patches': array([1,2,3]), 'cd_la': array([1,2,3])}, 'A_BA': {'patches': array([1,2,3]), 'cd_la': array([1,2,3])}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There’s no way for `val` to get rebound inside that `while` loop, so once you pop, you can’t stop.

Comment: Thanks for tour answer, could you be more specific?

Comment: Adding to @Samwise's answer: you create a loop: `while isinstance(val, dict):` so when `val` is a dictionary it enters the loop. Inside the loop, `val` never changes, so the loop can't exit — `val` is going to be a dict on every loop. Additionally, if the loop did exit, it would immediately fail the next line's assertion. I think you are misunderstandig the way names binding works in python. Since you haven't provided enough info to figure out what you're actually trying to do, it's hard to give advice. Maybe that `while` should be an `if`…or maybe you should be reassigning `val` in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem were with `while` which, should be replaced with `if`, anotrer strathe thing were `assert`.

So, here is working version:

```py
def apply_recursively_on_dict(dic, function, keys):
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            apply_recursively_on_dict(val, function, keys)

        if key in keys:
            dic[key] = function(val)

data = {'A_AB': {'patches': array([1,2,3]), 'cd_la': array([1,2,3])}, 'A_BA': {'patches': array([1,2,3]), 'cd_la': array([1,2,3])}}

print(data)

res = apply_recursively_on_dict(data, lambda el: sum(el), ['cd_la'])

print(data)
```

This will print:

```py
{'A_AB': {'patches': array([1, 2, 3]), 'cd_la': array([1, 2, 3])}, 'A_BA': {'patches': array([1, 2, 3]), 'cd_la': array([1, 2, 3])}}
{'A_AB': {'patches': array([1, 2, 3]), 'cd_la': 6}, 'A_BA': {'patches': array([1, 2, 3]), 'cd_la': 6}}
```

Comment: 2 nitpicks: if for some reason you have a key:value pair with key in keys and val is a dic, you might have a problem, so better replace `if key in keys:` with `elif...`; and you could replace the lambda in your example with just sum.